# Join with CharType GERMAN_VFP_CI_AS_437

Tags: .net, character-encoding, collation, advantage-database-server

I've got a problem with my dotnet application reading data from different tables of my advantage database server through a sql "join" statement. The tables are from an old clipper application, so the table type is "ntx". One *.dbf and several *.ntx files for each table.

I use the dotnet data provider to connect to the database. 
Connection String: Data Source=\PathToDatabase\database.add;Password=***;User ID=adssys;CharType=GENERAL_VFP_CI_AS_437;ServerType=REMOTE;LockMode=COMPATIBLE;Shared=True;TableType=NTX;UnicodeCollation=de_DE"

Everything works fine until applying a "join" in the sql statement. The server always returns an empty table.

Without setting the charType in the connection string, the server returns the correct result.

How is it possible to define a "join" statement with CharType set to GENERAL_VFP_CI_AS_437?

Answer (score 2):

The VFP-style collations are only supported for ADT and VFP file formats.  They are not supported with the NTX style tables.  [Some information is here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/master_collation_support.htm).

Unfortunately, it appears that an error check is either being bypassed or suppressed somehow with that usage when the NTX table is in the dictionary (as opposed to a free table).  The query (whether or not it includes a join) should be returning an error (error code 7200 with a 5025 native error).

In order to use that collation with a DBF table, it will be necessary to use the VFP table type.